# DB2 SQL Select with for each

Tags: sql, db2

I have  table for customers. Each customer might have X amount of steps associated with it.
So for example CUSTOMER1 can have BUY001, BUY002, BUY003 and SEL001, SEL002 steps associated with it.
CUSTOMER2 might have BAD001, BAD002, BOP001, BOP002 steps associated with it and etc..

| CUSTOMER_ID | STEP_ID | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUSTOMER1 | BUY001 | 2019-10-11 |
| CUSTOMER1 | BUY002 | 2019-10-12 |
| CUSTOMER1 | BUY003 | 2019-10-13 |
| CUSTOMER1 | SEL001 | 2019-10-13 |
| CUSTOMER1 | SEL002 | 2019-10-13 |
| CUSTOMER2 | BAD001 | 2020-10-10 |
| CUSTOMER2 | BAD002 | 2021-02-01 |
| CUSTOMER2 | BOP001 | 2022-02-02 |

What I am after is to create a query that would select only the LAST number for each STEP for each customer.
So expected output would be like this:

| CUSTOMER_ID | STEP_ID | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUSTOMER1 | BUY003 | 2019-10-13 |
| CUSTOMER1 | SEL002 | 2019-10-13 |
| CUSTOMER2 | BAD002 | 2021-02-01 |
| CUSTOMER2 | BOP001 | 2022-02-02 |

PS: Step list is a finite array consisting of 3 letter characters like BUY, SEL, etc.. but approx count is ~100. Also each different step has its own number. like BUY001, BUY002 and that might come up to 999.

Comment: Are you using DB2 or Oracle?

Comment: I am using DB2. But Oracle SQL developer to browse :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rownumber() to select the first by order of STEP_ID descending :

```
with T1 (CUSTOMER_ID, STEP_ID, TIMESTAMP) as (
VALUES
    ('CUSTOMER1', 'BUY001', date '2019-10-11'),
    ('CUSTOMER1', 'BUY002', date '2019-10-12'),
    ('CUSTOMER1', 'BUY003', date '2019-10-13'),
    ('CUSTOMER1', 'SEL001', date '2019-10-13'),
    ('CUSTOMER1', 'SEL002', date '2019-10-13'),
    ('CUSTOMER2', 'BAD001', date '2020-10-10'),
    ('CUSTOMER2', 'BAD002', date '2021-02-01'),
    ('CUSTOMER2', 'BOP001', date '2022-02-02')
)
select
  CUSTOMER_ID, STEP_ID, TIMESTAMP
from (
  select *, 
    rownumber() over (
       partition by customer_id, left(step_id, 3)
       order by step_id desc
    ) as rn
  from t1
) where rn = 1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? Not sure what you used but query seems to not work either in Oracle or DB2.

Comment: It work on [Db2](https://dbfiddle.uk/MLFWqdX1) and [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x3xtztwU).

Comment: try row_number()

Comment: @PetrasPaludnevičius what do you mean by "not work", do you have an error ?